# How to make cx_Freeze compile submodules into shared object (.so) files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

### Background

- I'm working for a company that is writing code to control television screens that will play advertisements downloaded via the internet.
- My boss wants to compile the source code before we give it to the factory that will be manufacturing the screen-controller computers so that the code can't easily be copied / reverse-engineered.
- My boss has decided that [`.pyc` files are too easy to reverse-engineer](https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e), and would prefer to compile to binary(?) files, one type of which(?) seems to be `.so` files.
- I'm now trying to use cx_Freeze to convert all of our source code to `.so` files.

### Problem

When I run `python setup.py build` (the command that has cx_Freeze "compile" our app), it seems only the one file I designate as the "main" file gets converted to an `.so` file, while the rest of our source code is converted to `.pyc`.  We want *all* of our code to be `.so` files.

### What I've tried

- I've tried going through the cx_Freeze documentation but don't see how to accomplish what we're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible.

I emailed the creator of cx_Freeze (Anthony Tuininga) and this was his response:

> cx_Freeze doesn't have that capability. It puts all of its compiled Python code (.pyc files) into a zip file. Technically, there is a way to do so, but cx_Freeze doesn't do so. Since it involves a C compiler its more complex and prone to error.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend looking towards pyinstaller and compilation for Linux, namely Glibc, if there is such a technical possibility.
Compilation will allow you to not install Python.